# Is it possible to change the view from a vue app (SPA) over node.js

Tags: node.js, vue.js, express

Is it possible to change the created views in a vue app over CRUD operations in node or express?

I mean i have a SPA Vue app, which has many routes.

Server side, i have a post methode to check the login, like:

```
app.post('/login',async (req,res) => {
  try {
  const formData = req.body
  const name = formData.name
  const pass = formData.password
  const checkUser = await user.findOne({name: name})
  const checkPass = await user.findOne({password: pass});

  if(checkUser && checkPass){
      session=req.session;
      session.userid=req.body.name;
      console.log(req.session)
      res.send(`Hey there, welcome <a href=\'/logout'>click to logout</a>`);

  }
  else{
      res.send('Invalid username or password');
      console.log(name)
  }
}catch(err){
  console.log(err)
}
})
```

And if the login was successfull, i want to change the router-view from the vue app.
Something like `res.send(<change here the view-route>`.
Or it should be redirect to a seperate `html` file for logged-in users???

Answer (score 0):

`res.redirect("/your_route")` if you use browser history.

`res.redirect("/#your_route")` if you use hash history.

if you use fetch or ajax in browser, you should response json, and handle after login action in browser, not the restful api here.